# VBA code for navigating IE is not working

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, sorry for any mistakes in the text, English is not my native language. Second, I've searched a lot in the internet about this, but was not able to find the solution. Programming is a hobby that I'm beginning, so sorry in advance if the question is basic.

So, I'm building a code to navigate to a site, fill in the login and password, enter the site. After the loading, navigate to another link, select a option in a dropbox. Then I need to upload a document to the site (click a button to open the explorer so I can find the file I want) and send it.

My code is working until waiting after the login. Then when I have to navigate to another link, the code just ends.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

Const cUsername = "xxxxx"
Const cPassword = "xxxxx"

sURL = "https://sta.previc.gov.br/staweb/Login.xhtml"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Visible = True
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.navigate sURL
'oBrowser.FullScreen = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document
Do
' Wait till the document is loaded
Loop Until HTMLDoc.readyState = "complete"

HTMLDoc.getelementbyid("loginForm:usernameInput").Focus
HTMLDoc.getelementbyid("loginForm:usernameInput").Value = cUsername
HTMLDoc.getelementbyid("loginForm:passwordInput").Focus
HTMLDoc.getelementbyid("loginForm:passwordInput").Value = cPassword
HTMLDoc.getelementbyid("loginForm:j_idt30").Click


Do
' Wait till the document is loaded
Loop Until HTMLDoc.readyState = "complete"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If oHTML_Element.innerText = "Envio de arquivos" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click
        Do
        ' Wait till the document is loaded
        Loop Until HTMLDoc.readyState = "complete"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The link code I need to click after the load is in this

[image: link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a manually break for a few seconds after clicking the log in button. I think the reason is, the ready state of the IE is still set to complete after load the page first time.

Try the folowing to break for 5 seconds after clicking the log in button:

```
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(pause_hours, pause_minutes, pause_seconds))
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))
```